# Javascript form validation not empty or no whitespaces

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm trying to validate a form I'm creating and can't seem to understand how this works. I'm trying to make sure the field isn't empty or contains no white-spaces I have validated it server side but not client side.

Could someone please show me the code like below to validate against being empty or having no white-spaces?

I see these below and this is what I thought they did:

```
x===null // means if field is empty
x===""  // on trying this means if the field is empty
x===" " // and this checks if there is 1 white space
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
        if (x===null || x===""|| x===" ") {
            alert("First name must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: i have voted up this to

Comment: You ask for code that checks for “no whitespace”, but you have accepted an answer that does not do that. You have not specified what should actually be checked. You do not specify how your code fails to do what you want. You should generally describe data validation in terms of what the data *should* contain and what it should be like, rather than incompletely describing what it should *not* be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using javascript `trim()` function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
        if (x.trim()==null || x.trim()==""|| x===" ") {
            alert("First name must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: This does not check against “no whitespace”, which is what the question explicitly asks for (probably mistakenly, but still).